# Managed Wordpress website hosted on Aruba slow

Tags: wordpress, mobile-website, aruba

my problem is that I have a site built with wordpress hosted on Aruba with a wordpress managed hosting plan.  Today it started to go very slow.  The loading time is over 13 seconds.  Until yesterday it was fine.  What can it be?  Thanks.

Comment: If nothing in the code has been changed and the performance loss will persist, your best bet is probably to contact your hosting provider for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things can be causing your WordPress to be slow: configuration of your server, WordPress configuration, images and videos, theme and plugins's code, external scripts.

So, within that list, here are some of the tasks you should consider doing:

- Speed test the website again
- Use latest PHP version
- Make sure all updates are done
- If you create backups, make sure that they are only run during low traffic time
- Install a caching plugin
- Optimize images
- Reduce as much as possible videos which costs bandwidth
- Analyze if the theme is optimized for speed
- Analyze if plugins are poorly coded
- Reduce external HTTP requests and DB calls
- Optimize the DB

If none of this works, contact your hosting provider and explain what you've done so far. If they don't care for the situation or are not capable to serve your needs, consider changing your hosting provider.